# How does a Run Loop work?

Tags: ios

Out a curiosity, how does a Run Loop work? The [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html) say

> The purpose of a run loop is to keep your thread busy when there is work to do and put your thread to sleep when there is none.

How is this implemented efficiently? Is the run loop actually a loop that is constantly running? ie. `while(true)`?

Comment: If you really want to know, the underlying [`CFRunLoop` is open source](https://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-855.11/CFRunLoop.c.auto.html)

Comment: "How is this implemented efficiently?" ... Do you mean how does the OS do this efficiently for the main run loop? Or do you mean how do you implement your own run loops running on secondary threads in your own code? The answer to the latter is that it's not generally as efficient as other patterns and we use it less nowadays than we might have in days of yore.

Comment: I'm wondering about the underlying OS for the main run loop. It seems that `CFRunLoopRun` is an important function that runs until `kCFRunLoopRunStopped=true` or `kCFRunLoopRunFinished=true`. I'm more interested in how this loop is running without draining the battery. Is it running million times a second, constantly polling for input? Or there an optimization that allows it to run only a dozen times per second, at critical moments when there is input.

Comment: As the quote you include in your question says, it will “put your thread to sleep when there is [no work to do]”. So, no, it won’t drain the battery spinning unnecessarily when there are no inputs to process.

Answer (score 0):

I understand it as something waiting for inputs to come to do things.

For example, when you use your phone, the screen is displaying things but at the same time it is waiting for any inputs to come do stuff. Inputs can be you touching the screen, someone sending you a text, some scheduled alarm ready to ring, etc.

Thus using a run loop would be describing all the accepted inputs (events, schedule, etc.) with handlers, and when that is done, start waiting for those inputs to come.

> The purpose of a run loop is to keep your thread busy when there is
>   work to do and put your thread to sleep when there is none.

This means that every time your loop is waiting for inputs, concerned thread will be idle, and once an input comes, the thread will be active and execute the stuff it needs to.